# Finding a point in polygon in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using the following code to find a point of coordinates exists in the code or not:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() 
{
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) 
    {
        boolean checkPoly = true;
        Point2D[] points = new Point2D[ myPoints.size()];
        for ( int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i ++)
        {
            LatLng pt = myPoints.get(i);
            points[i] = new Point2D(pt.latitude, pt.longitude);
        }
        Polygon2D polygon2d = new SimplePolygon2D(points);

        double a = point.latitude;
        double b = point.longitude;
        Point2D myPt = new Point2D(a,b);

        checkPoly = polygon2d.contains(myPt);
        Log.i("CHECK", String.valueOf(checkPoly));
        if (checkPoly)
        {
            setMarker(point);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(NewSearch.this,"The Location is outside of the Area", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I am using the JavaGeom 0.11.1 library for finding polygon point. However this code was working exactly fine. Note that `myPoints` array is an `ArrayList<LatLng>` of all vertices of the polygons drawn on map. However something happened and now it's working for opposite that is outside of map; if i change `!checkPoly` then it works fine.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [source for the polygon boundary definition](https://sourceforge.net/p/geom-java/code/357/tree/trunk/src/math/geom2d/polygon/LinearRing2D.java).  It's using the usual convention for "inside," which requires the vertices to be given in CCW order around the "inside" space. It's likely your boundary is given in CW order, which makes the "inside" what most people would call the outside.

In other words, what you think is a polygon is really a hole in the infinite polygon that covers the whole x-y universe.

So reverse the order of boundary vertices and things should start working as you intend.

**ADDITION**

If you can't reverse the order of vertices, there is a different polygon membership test that doesn't rely on point order.  If you are testing membership of the point (x,y), this algorithm assumes that the point (infinity, y) is outside the polygon and then decides whether (x,y) is on the opposide side.  The [implementation here in C is due to WR Franklin](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html).  It would be easy to port this to Java.  I've used it several times with excellent results.

Comment: what do you mean by reverse the order ? should i change longitude with latitude and viceversa?

Comment: No.  The first point should become the last.  The second becomes the second last, etc.

Comment: for ( int i = myPoints.size()-1; i >= 0; i --)
     {
      LatLng pt = myPoints.get(i);
      points[i] = new Point2D(pt.latitude, pt.longitude); did this, however i saw that those polygons that are drawn CW are working fine however thoe who are CCW not working

Comment: how can i find it using code if the curve made was CCW Or CW?

Comment: Please look at the addition to the article.  It shows a link to 7 lines of code that will do a test that does not rely on vertex order.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Google android-maps-utils library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) and you can make use of the PolyUtil class, particularly at this method:

```
public static boolean containsLocation(LatLng point, List<LatLng> polygon, boolean geodesic)
```